# consuming multiple Webservices on Android

Tags: java, web-services

I'm creating an android app and I need to consume multiple webservices, Is there anything to take into account in order to call different webservices on the same activity? Which are the best methods to do so?
I already did this for IOS (Objective-C) and what I did was create different NSObject Class in order to call the different webservices and everything worked fine. Is it going to be the same with Java?

What I found reading for now is [Ksoap2](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) that seems perfect for what I need but I'd like to hear others opinion.

**EDIT:**

What I need to know is if I need to create multiple async task for every of my url or creating a single class that downloads every json data and then parse it on the callback method.
What is the best solution?

Comment: Is the web service that you're consuming based on SOAP?

Comment: @Simon sorry, I forgot to mention it.. I'm using REST - Json webservices

Comment: I don't know Ksoap2 but it looks like it's for SOAP and not REST

Comment: well as i prefer spring tools for java if you are familiar with it ,i should suggest the spring's rest client , although i haven't test its performance myself over android (you have to check how much time it takes to initialize a template) ,  it should fit your need , async - light - fast coding , check it out : https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-android/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several aspects to keep in mind when calling a remote service:
First of all you can't call the webservice in the main thread because if the server takes too long to response then Android will kill your app:
**ANR (Application Not Responding)**.
 You should call in a separate thread. You can use *AsyncTask* but it could suffer of memory leakage so be aware of it. There are other solution:

1. Volley it is one of the best way to make HTTP request, it runs the request in separe thread and you don't have to worry about ANR problems
2. OkHTTP is another populare library that handles HTTP requests and response

When it comes the time to parse the response there are several methods. You could implement the logic manually if the response is easy to parse or you can use *Gson*. You could give a look [here](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-volley-library-example/).

If you want to use volley, you should:

```
 private RequestQueue queue;

 public void init(Context ctx) {       
    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx);
}
```

..

```
StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String data) {
                   // Parse here if you parse the response manually
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    //handle error
                }
            }
    );

    queue.add(req); // Add request to queue
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Volley seems the best solution. One last thing, If I have to do multiple webservices call on the same activity what should I do? concatenate multiple queue? For example calling the next webservice on the onResponse method?

Comment: I would prefer to call them cuncurrently if possible. You can use your approch if you have to pass to the next WS some data extracted from the previous one.

Comment: yeah I have to pass data from the previous one. Ty i'll try this approach!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things that I think should be kept in mind

**Call web services asynchronously**. 
If you're calling several web services in one Activity, this will improve your performance.
You can either make each call inside a [AsynchTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) using [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) or you can use `AsyncHTTPClient`.

**Use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to go from JSON to a java POJO instance.**
This saves you from parsing the JSON by hand or using a low level JSON API.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! One last question, can you explain me how does Java handle multiple Webservices calls? Because my fear is that If I don't choose the right approach to this problem i'll have tons of exception on my code